# accessing non static data members

Tags: c++, static, static-methods

My lecturer asked a question that I can't find its satisfactory answer. Quote from him " *Just tell me a sentence why cannot static functions(methods) access to non-static data members?* " Could you tell me why? I want to learn.

Comment: What's *your* answer?  What do you interpret static/non-static to mean?

Comment: non-static means should be private/public member variables @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: Well, static functions CAN access non-static data members.. if you pass an instance of the class as a parameter. What it cannot do is access the `this` pointer, explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: static variables can also be private/public members.

Answer (score 0):

`static` method can be called on the class itself, no instance of that class is necessary.

This means that there is no instance of the class and so non-static data members have not been created and initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can call static methods using the syntax `ClassName::MethodName()`.
In this case you are not accessing an concrete object and hence you can not
access non-static members.

Consider the following code:

```
class C {
public:
    C(int i) { _i = i; }
    int getI() { return _i; } // ok

    /* error: using non-static member in a static method */
    static int sgetI() { return _i; } 
private:
    int _i;
};

int main(void) {
    C c1(1);
    C c2(2);

    int n1 = c1.getI(); // ok, n1 = 1
    int n2 = c2.getI(); // ok, n2 = 2    
    int n3 = C::sgetI(); // what? does not make sense!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`static-method` and `static-member`s are common among the all the instances of class.
So when you try to access `non-static` data-members the compiler can't decide what is the memory address of that `non-static` data-member. Remember, class is just a template, while object is one who has the address and stores the data in that particular format defined in class.

---

Let's take an example :

- for the sake of argument let's assume C++ static method allows us to access non-static data-members. Let's create a class named `person` with `name` as string data member and two methods `get_name()` and `put_name()`

```
class person
{
    string name;
    public : 
    void get_name(){cin >> name;}
    static void put_name(){cout << name << "\n";}
};
```

Now writing the driver program...

```
int main()
{
    person p1,p2;
    p1.get_name(); // input : alice
    p2.get_name(); // input : bob
    
    person :: put_name();
    return 0;
}
```

*We can clearly observe after taking two names as inputs, when we call `put_name()` what output the compiler would give? alice, bob or NULL ? because static member function is not affiliated with any of object it can't decide what to give as an output.*

---

So now maybe it is clear that  **why cannot static functions(methods) access to non-static data members?**. If you got your answer hope you appreciate the effort.